# c# rdlc Dataset properties data source error

Tags: c#, dataset, report, datasource, rdlc

Please help,

I have a C# desktop application with .rdlc report and I use visual studio 2017
the report takes data from an object. for example:

```
public int ID {get; set;}
public string Name {get; set;}
```

the report is working very well BUT I needed to add a new field,

I added the field to the object and now I need to modify the report dataset

I removed the old dataset like I always do,
and then on report data window -right click on Datasets to choose New Dataset

now the dataset properties window opened and also popped up the data source configuration wizard,

this was not happening

anyway I chose (Object) as a data source type and --Next

in the next form I selected the object that I want and clicked --finish

**error message popped up saying (Object reference not set to an instance of an object.)**

The data source option is empty and choosing new and doing the same steps above did not solve it

I retried many times but it is the same
All references are correct

The application won't build because the dataset name is missing because I already deleted the dataset and not able to add any data new datasets

this never happened with me before
I am trying to delete the data source to redefine it again but I see no option for that

please tell me what should I do for that

Comment: I would use SQL Server Management Studio and connect to database.  Then using the explorer check under management to see log files.   There are also error logs under the SQL Report Server in Apps in the START button.  I can't tell if this error is coming from the report manager or the database.  The RDLC file is text and is in HTML format.  You open the RDLC with an text editor.  The is a query string under the HTML  tag Command_Text to see the actual query.  Some RDLC will create a temporary file or a View in the database.  To read a rdlc report you send a HTTP Request to the report manager.

Comment: Most Reports you send a HTTP Request to the server using a URL, the server queries the database with a build in Command_Text, and then the results of query is put into a HTTP Response.  The request can have parameters (either in URL or HTTP headers).  The RDLC also has a connection string and the connection string may be causing the error.

Comment: I am working on a desktop winform application, and there is no sql queries whereas my data is taken from an object in the report.

Comment: Do you have old RDLC file?  RDLC file is HTML format which is text.  I would compare new and old RDLC with a compare tool like BeyondCompare.

Comment: the problem is not coming from the RDLC file itself, but the data set and the data source, I don't know I'm still trying different things.

Comment: You can take the Command_Text from RDLC and test in SQL Server Management Studio.  The command text is HTML so you may need to modify special characters from `&amp;` to & to run in SSMS.  Otherwise the query is the same.  did you check error logs?